# Notarization of app built using PyInstaller fails due to PyQt dylib files not being signed or not including a valid time stamp

Tags: macos, pyinstaller, code-signing

My app was constructed using Python and Pyinstaller and utilizes both tkinter and PyQt5. Codesign produces no error messages and I'm able upload it for notarization, but notarization fails.

The LogFileURL produces 24 error messages, all indicating a binary was not signed or the signature does not contain a valid timestamp. Here are two examples:

```
{
  "severity": "error",
  "code": null,
  "path": "My_Application.zip/My_Application.app/Contents/Resources/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.dylib",
  "message": "The binary is not signed.",
  "docUrl": null,
  "architecture": "x86_64"
}
```

,and

```
{
  "severity": "error",
  "code": null,
  "path": "My_Application_10_7.zip/My_Application_10_7.app/Contents/Resources/PyQt5/Qt/qml/QtQml/WorkerScript.2/libworkerscriptplugin.dylib",
  "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
  "docUrl": null,
  "architecture": "x86_64"
}
```

What's common about all the errors is that the dylib resides in a subdirectory of PyQt5 whose name contains a period.

Ben Hagen describes how such a presence of periods can prevent signing and provides a workaround script at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing-Qt. I used this tool to get my app signed successfully. But somehow I need to do something more prior to uploading for notarization.